# Error in creating SQL table using python script

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create a sql table using python script.

Here is the code :

```
import MySQLdb
db1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="")
cursor = db1.cursor()
sql = 'use test'
cursor.execute(sql)
query='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 3112017(service_area_code VARCHAR(100),phone_numbers VARCHAR(100),preferences VARCHAR(100),opstype VARCHAR(100),phone_type VARCHAR(100))'
cursor.execute(query)
db1.commit()
```

Following is the error I am getting:

```
cursor.execute(query)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3112017(service_area_code VARCHAR(100),phone_numbers VARCHAR(100),preferences VA' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the traceback, you have an error in your SQL syntax. Table name is wrong.

From the [SQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) -

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.